# angular 2 ngIf Unexpected token #

Tags: angular, components, angular-ng-if

Hi everyone i'm study angular2 now im workind with `*ngIf` and i have this code

```
<div *ngIf='courses.length > 0 ; then #coursesList else #noCourses'>
</div>
<ng-template #coursesList>
  <h1>List of courses</h1>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #noCourses>
  <h2>No courses yet</h2> 
</ng-template>
```

And this is my `component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app hello';

    courses=[];
}
```

My problem is when i run the web site i have this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token # at column 27 in [courses.length > 0 ; then 
#coursesList else #noCourses] in ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@1:5 ("
<h1>Angular</h1>
<div [ERROR ->]*ngIf='courses.length > 0 ; then #coursesList else 
#noCourses'>
</div>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@1:5
```

I don't understand why i'm follow a guide in don't want use copy paste because i need know why is happen this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the # in front of `coursesList` and `noCourses`. # is used only on the ng-template tag.

```
<div *ngIf='courses.length > 0 ; then coursesList else noCourses'>
</div>
```